# .htaccess: How to redirect all pages except admin to home page?

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I modified the home page to "under construction" page. Now I want to redirect all pages within the site to the "under construction" page except for the admin section. How can I do this with .htaccess?

For instance, I want to redirect pages such as `www.mydomain.com/contact` or `www.mydomain.com/profile/services` to the home page. But I want to keep all admin pages such as `www.mydomain.com/admin` still accessible as I need to login to make changes.

This is what I have:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.mydomain\.com
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.mydomain.com/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}/index.html !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}/index.php !-f
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

I tried few different things but it does not seem to work.

Answer (score 1):

You can use these rules:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.mydomain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.mydomain.com/$1 [R=301,L,NE]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.(?:jpe?g|gif|bmp|png|tiff|css|js)$ [NC]
RewriteRule !^admin / [L,NC,R=302]
```

Comment: No it does not seem to have any effect on subpages. Instead, it also removed images from the home page.

Comment: see update to fix image/css (though you should have mentioned this requirement in question). Also you need to tell me which URI is not getting redirected to home page.

Answer (score 0):

How about testing if `admin` then if so, stop rewrite rules?

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /

    # Testing if `admin` then if so, stop rewrite rules
    RewriteRule (.*)/admin(.*) - [QSA,L,NC]

    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.mydomain\.com
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.mydomain.com/$1 [R=301,L]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}/index.html !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}/index.php !-f
    RewriteRule . index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```